# images break when I add php and upload the files on the server

Tags: css

So all my images have correctly configured administrative rights, etc.. They're all 777, just for localhost anyway. When I made my css and the site, it looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/3d0lpa

When I add PhP, it looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/3d0m1m

This is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

     <title>Follow the white rabbit</title>
     <meta name="description" content="IRC">
     <style>
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF; }   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
*{
     padding : 0;
     margin : 0;
     border : 0;
}
body{
     background-image:url('Backgrounds/Matrix.gif');
     opacity:6.6
    }
.kontejner{
     display : block;
     width : 1100px;
     overflow : auto;
     margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.glava{
background-image:url('Logos/logo2.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
     background-color : black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.levidiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.levigordiv{
    opacity:0.8;
     background-color: black;
     float : none;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 200px;

}
.vsebina{
    background-image:url('Backgrounds/rabbit.jpg');
    background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 600px;
     width : 592px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.desnidiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;

}
.desnigordiv{
     background-color: black;
     float : right;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 197px;
     border-right: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.noga{
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     opacity:0.8;
     border: 1px solid green;
}
a: hover
{
background-color:red;
}
.meniji
{
color: green;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="kontejner">
      <div class="glava">
      </div>
      <div class="levidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Login</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Register</p></a>
          <div class="levigordiv">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vsebina">
      </div>
      <div class="desnidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">IRC</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Scan</p></a>
          <div class="desnigordiv">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="noga"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Home</p></a>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the not working code:

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

     <title>Follow the white rabbit</title>
     <meta name="description" content="IRC">
     <style>
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF; }   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
*{
     padding : 0;
     margin : 0;
     border : 0;
}
body{
     background-image:url('Backgrounds/Matrix.gif');
     opacity:6.6
    }
.kontejner{
     display : block;
     width : 1100px;
     overflow : auto;
     margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.glava{
background-image:url('Logos/logo2.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
     background-color : black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.levidiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.levigordiv{
    opacity:0.8;
     background-color: black;
     float : none;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 200px;

}
.vsebina{
    background-image:url('Backgrounds/rabbit.jpg');
    background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 600px;
     width : 592px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.desnidiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;

}
.desnigordiv{
     background-color: black;
     float : right;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 197px;
     border-right: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.noga{
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     opacity:0.8;
     border: 1px solid green;
}
a: hover
{
background-color:red;
}
.meniji
{
color: green;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="kontejner">
      <div class="glava">
      </div>
      <div class="levidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Login</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Register</p></a>
          <div class="levigordiv">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vsebina">  <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="desnidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">IRC</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Scan</p></a>
          <div class="desnigordiv">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="noga"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Home</p></a>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html.php

```
<?php ob_start() ?>

<p>Hello.</p>


<?php $content = ob_get_clean() ?>

<?php ob_start() ?>
Glavna stran
<?php $title = ob_get_clean() ?>
<?php require 'layout.html.php' ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['stran']) && $_GET['stran']=='login')
{
    include 'Templates/Login/login.html.php';
}
else
{
    include 'Templates/index.html.php';
}


?>
```

This is how the folders are placed:

http : / / prntscr . com / 3d0nzd

The index.php is just one folder back.

--UPDATE--

I think the issue is in index.php. Without this index, my layout and images work perfectly!!!

Comment: It's your images that are breaking, not your css. Make sure your paths are correct

Comment: You can see how all my folders are placed, I have a file named layout in the same directory as the folder Backgrounds. And my layout route is Backgrounds/image.jpg

Comment: I figured out the issue!!!

Okay so my index.php manages my website. It co trolls all my html and php files, including layout.html.php and index.html.php .

THAT'S WHY when I have to specify an image path in layout.html.php, I have to set the location as if I were located in the index.php!!! 

So my index.php is outside of the Templates folder, and my layout and all other stuff is in the Templates folder!!! So when I'm specifying an image path in the layout.html.php, I have to set the image path to:
Templates/background.jpg

I hope this makes things clear!